# Как заранее закешировать картинки в CSS-меню?

Tags: веб-программирование, css

Имеем CSS-меню со сменой фонового изображения для каждого пункта. Некоторые пункты имеют скругления, некоторые имеют изображения стрелочки (дескать тут будут своё под-меню).

Браузер при выпадании такого меню часто отображает часть этих пунктов сначала без фонового изображения, подгружая его с некоторой задержкой. А наводишь мышкой на пункт (должен поменятся фон пункта) - и опять сначала показывает пустой фон.

Как сделать так, чтоб при загрузке страницы заранее прокешировались все картинки, лежащие в определенном каталоге?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - по ходу формирования меню все картинки добавлять в массив, а потом выводить их где угодно со стилем

```
.preloadedImage { position: absolute; visibility: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1px; }
```

Тогда они подгрузятся вместе с документом.

Answer (score 1):

Картинки нужно загрузить в спрайт или сделать их иконочным шрифтом, тогда они загрузятся одним файлом и не будут мигать.